# Enabling Google Container Engine API don't automatically enable Google Compute Engine API

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-platform

Recently I experienced that enabling "Google Container Engine API" via web console or gcloud command didn't automatically enable "Google Compute Engine API" on new GCP projects. As a result, I run into error when I tried to create container cluster via API. The error messages in the response is shown below.
Off-course, enabling "Google Compute Engine API" by hand ease the error.

> Google Compute Engine: Access Not Configured. Compute Engine API has not been used in project 123456789012 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/compute-component.googleapis.com/overview?project=123456789012 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.

It was work fine when I did the same operations at 2017-02-24 without enable "Google Compute Engine API" explicitly.
I wonder if this was intended change or some bugs on API dependencies management.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It was work fine when I did the same operations at 2017-02-24 without enable "Google Compute Engine API" explicitly. I wonder if this was intended change or some bugs on API dependencies management.

This has recently been fixed (coincidentally within a few hours of your question being posted). I just manually verified by creating a new project, verifying that both the Google Container Engine API and Google Compute Engine API were disabled, enabling the Google Container Engine API, and then verifying that both the Google Container Engine API and Google Compute Engine API were now enabled.